# Transpose Range of a Column at a Time- Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, transpose

I have a dataframe like this,

```
  id    pd  pd_dt      pd_tp    pd.1    pd_dt.1     pd_tp.1 pd.2    pd_dt.2     pd_tp.2
0  1    100 per year   468      200     per year    400     300     per year    320
1  2    100 per year   60       200     per year    890     300     per year    855
```

Now, I need an output like this,

```
id Transposed_value
1  100
1  per year
1  468
1  200
1  per year
1  400
1  300
1  per year
1  320
2  100
2  per year
2  360
2  200
2  per year
2  890
2  300
2  per year
2  855
```

If you see, `pd`, `pd_dt`, `pd_tp` are repeating with `pd.1` ..

I tried,

`df.T`

This does not give me my desired output. Any suggestion or help to achieve my results would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
df.set_index('id').stack().reset_index(name='Transposed_value').drop('level_1',axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
   id   Transposed_value
0   1   100
1   1   per year
2   1   468
3   1   200
4   1   per year
5   1   400
6   1   300
7   1   per year
8   1   320
9   2   100
10  2   per year
11  2   60
12  2   200
13  2   per year
14  2   890
15  2   300
16  2   per year
17  2   855
```